# Is there a term for using capitals mid-word (such as SmartTask and HiSuite)?

Tags: capitalization

So far, I have only noticed capitals being used in the middle of a word in products marketed as computer applications.

I wondered if there was a term for this and I also wondered if it ever occurs outside of that particular context.

Comment: Looks like branding. But I have used the technique to spotlight a letter in an acronym or keyboard shortcut (use Alt-O for fOrmat.)

Comment: @Hachi Thank you. Answered.

Comment: I've seen them called StudlyCaps.

Comment: @JohnLawler Googling 'Studlycaps' also brings up 'StickyCaps'

Comment: ThatIsCalledCamelCase ——— sTuDLy cApS iS tHiS oNe.

Comment: And -- This Kind of Thing is Called Title Case (major words first word capitalised). And This Is Called Proper Case (all words with first letter capitalised).

Comment: @NigelJ, You might want to read [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/533036/what-is-this-kind-of-capitalisation-called-random-capitalisation-or-intermitt/533037#533037).