# Is there a term for proper nouns with multiple capitalised letters?

Tags: terminology

I am looking for a way to classify proper nouns that have multiple capitalised letters within the same word. Most examples are company or product names such as *SteamVR* or *LinkedIn*.

If there is a term for this classification, what is it called?

Comment: Probably a duplicate: [What is this kind of capitalisation called ... random capitalisation?  intermittent capitalisation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/533036/what-is-this-kind-of-capitalisation-called-random-capitalisation-or-intermitt) (yields 'camel case' for non-random examples).

Comment: _StudlyCaps_ is what they used to be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Bicapitalization** (or **BiCapitalization**) is the use of a capital letter in the middle of a word or name—usually a brand name or a
> company name, such as *iPod* and *ExxonMobil*.
>
> In compound names, when two words are joined without spaces, the first
> letter of the second word is usually the one that's capitalized, as in
> *DreamWorks*.
>
> Among the numerous synonyms for **bicapitalization** (sometimes shortened
> to ***bicaps***) are *CamelCase, embedded caps, InterCaps* (short for *internal
> capitalization*), *medial capitals*, and *midcaps*.
>
> **Examples and Observations**
>
> "[A] distinctive feature of Internet graphology is the way two
> capitals are used—one initial, one medial--a phenomenon variously
> called **bicapitalization** *(BiCaps), intercaps, incaps,* and *midcaps*.
> Some style guides inveigh against this practice, but it is widespread:
> AltaVista, RetrievalWare, ScienceDirect, ThomsonDirect, NorthernLight,
> PostScript, PowerBook, DreamWorks, GeoCities, EarthLink, PeaceNet,
> SportsZone, HotWired, CompuServe, AskJeeves
> More complex examples
> include *QuarkXPress* and *aRMadillo Online.* Some of the new names cause
> difficulty, in that long-standing orthographic conventions are
> contravened: for example, sentences can begin with small letters, as
> in *eBay is interested or iMac* is the answer, a problem that faces
> anyone who wants to start a sentence with a lower-case username or
> program command."
> (David Crystal, *Language and the Internet*, 2nd ed.
> Cambridge University Press, 2006)
>
> [Richard Nordquist; "**Bicapitalization**, From DreamWorks to YouTube", Updated on February 12, 2020](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-bicapitalization-names-1689025) [See the article for further discussion.]

> **BiCapitalization** The use of capital letters within a name to visually delimit names that are composite words, for example "the
> InsertString function". [Philip Laplante; *Dictionary of Computer
> Science, Engineering and Technology*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dictionary_of_Computer_Science_Engineeri/PghEDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=bicapitalization&pg=PT105&printsec=frontcover) (2017)

> The earliest St. Joe town adjoins Seaside and is called WaterColor.
> The **bicapitalization** suggests ExxonMobil and TimeWarner and
> through this association establishes the aura of affluence that is
> critically important to the developer. After all, prices at WaterColor
> are astronomical in comparison to historical house prices in the
> neighborhood. [Michael Conzen; *The Making of the American
> Landscape*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Making_of_the_American_Landscape/V-m4AwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=bicapitalization&pg=PA465&printsec=frontcover) (2014)
>
> In the dinosaur days of computers, some machines printed only capital
> letters. Ever since, computer users have had a unique attitude toward
> upper and lower case letters. **Bicapitalization** describes the
> practice of inserting caps inside words as with these trademarks:
> WordPerfect, Next, Genie, Tex, VisiCalc, dBASE, Frame Maker, and
> CompuServe ... [*English Journal*, Vol. 84, p.69](https://www.google.com/books/edition/English_Journal/1KBiAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=bicapitalization&dq=bicapitalization&printsec=frontcover) (1995)